# How can I selectively NULL out values from one column but not another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I select all from my dbo.targetsvssales table I get the following result:

```
    Date   | Sales | Targets
_____________________________
2017-01-01     10      10
2017-02-01     19      20
2017-03-01     31      30
2017-04-01     38      40
2017-05-01     49      50
2017-06-01     62      60
2017-07-01     70      70
2017-08-01     75      80
2017-09-01     88      90
2017-10-01     101     100
2017-11-01     105     110
2017-12-01     105     120
```

I would like to only select the sales data that is from a date less than the current date, leaving the result of future dates as null, but keep the target values as they are. So the desired result from the select statement would be:

```
    Date   | Sales | Targets
_____________________________
2017-01-01     10      10
2017-02-01     19      20
2017-03-01     31      30
2017-04-01     38      40
2017-05-01     49      50
2017-06-01     62      60
2017-07-01     70      70
2017-08-01     75      80
2017-09-01     88      90
2017-10-01     101     100
2017-11-01     105     110
2017-12-01     NULL    120
```

This needs to be able to work year round, as well as on tables with weekly and daily precision as the Date column, so something that uses

```
WHERE DATE > GETDATE()
```

or something similar would be ideal. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `case when date > getdate() then null else date end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` to define the result for this column:

```
CASE WHEN DATE <= GETDATE()
     THEN Sales
 END AS Sales
```

Note I've reversed your logic and skipped the `else null` because this is anyway default if omitted.

More about case: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

Answer (score 0):

Case will work for this problem.

```
CASE WHEN DATE<=GETDATE() THEN Sales ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
select Date, case when Date > getdate() then NULL else Sales end as Sales, Targets 
from dbo.targetsvssales
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51b5af/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cas When statement

```
select date,
 CASE 
  WHEN Date <= GETDATE()
  THEN Sales
  else NULL
 End as Sales,
 targets
from dbo.targetsvssales
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and `CASE`:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    MDate DATE,
    Sales INT,
    Targetes INT
    );

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2017-01-01',     10 ,     10),
('2017-02-01',     19 ,     20),
('2017-03-01',     31 ,     30),
('2017-04-01',     38 ,     40),
('2017-05-01',     49 ,     50),
('2017-06-01',     62 ,     60),
('2017-07-01',     70 ,     70),
('2017-08-01',     75 ,     80),
('2017-09-01',     88 ,     90),
('2017-10-01',     101,     100),
('2017-11-01',     105,     110),
('2017-12-01',     105,     120);

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Sales ORDER BY MDate) RN
FROM T
    )
    SELECT MDate, CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Sales ELSE NULL END AS Sales, Targetes
    FROM CTE;
```

If you really want to compare with `GETDATE()`, then I'll suggest using `IIF` or `CASE` as:

```
SELECT MDate, IIF(IIF(MDate <= GetDate(), Sales, NULL) AS Sales, Targetes
FROM T;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/FABE43803)**

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @targetsvssales AS TABLE ([Date] DATE,   Sales MONEY, Targets MONEY)
INSERT INTO @targetsvssales VALUES
('2017-01-01',10,10),
('2017-02-01',19,20),
('2017-03-01',31,30),
('2017-04-01',38,40),
('2017-05-01',49,50),
('2017-06-01',62,60),
('2017-07-01',70,70),
('2017-08-01',75,80),
('2017-09-01',88,90),
('2017-10-01',101,100),
('2017-11-01',105,110),
('2017-12-01',105,120)

SELECT
 [Date] 
,CASE WHEN [DATE] > GETDATE() THEN NULL ELSE Sales END AS Sales 
,Targets

FROM @targetsvssales
```